# How to upload model against image in p5.js?

Tags: 3d, p5.js

I am trying to code a very simple layout of a 3D model against an image. I have uploaded 3D models before but never against an image background, and somehow I cannot find out how to upload both and have both in the sketch. When I add WEBGL in createCanvas, it stops the background image from loading. Does anyone know a solution for this?

```
let clay;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("NODO1.jpg");
  clay = loadModel("nodo.obj", true);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  img.resize(720, 400);
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```